# Spring data Jest version and Amazon ES versions, correlation between them

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm trying to use [Spring data Jest](https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-data-jest) in order to interact with an Amazon ES cluster. Right now, 18/04/2018, Amazon documentation says that the [available versions of ES](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/faqs/) are "6.2, 6.0, **5.5**, 5.3, 5.1, 2.3, and **1.5**".

According to Spring Data Jest documentation, the ES supported versions are "**1.5.2**, 2.2.0, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, and **5.5.0**".

So this means that I'm only capable of using Spring Data Jest library on ES 1.5 and 5.5.0? This ones are the only match that I see but perhaps I'm missing something.

I really want to use the latest version available but without using Spring Boot 2.X...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ElasticSearch HighLevel RestClient API instead of JEST.  The latest version of the API is 6.2

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html

HighLevelRest Client is a straight forward API and easy to use.

Comment: Hi Phani, thank you for your answer. Using ElasticSearch HighLevel RestClient API will force me to use Spring Boot 2.X , that's why I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: Instead of using the Elasticsearch repository provided by SpringBoot you can code your own client and repositories using the maven dependency. SpringBoot version you are using should allow you to do this.

Comment: I ended up doing a client on my own based on the low level rest client of elastic search

Comment: That's cool.  Please share the github link may be I will learn.